# prevent double execution of code in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, post, shopping-cart

I have a store which works like this:

1. The user adds stuff to his cart on the 1<sup>st</sup> page
2. The user submits the cart (*POST*), all post data is stored in the session.
3. The user fills out the form on the 2<sup>nd</sup> page, clicks submit again (second *POST*)
4. The user comes at the "thank you" page (3<sup>rd</sup>), which takes all the session data, and the form *POST*s the data and mails it.

The problem is, a simple refresh causes an empty table to be sent per email. How can I prevent this? Can I redirect somehow after the execution of the mail function? So the thank you page doesn't do anything on refresh?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: If table is empty, don't send! This is too vague.

Comment: so basically i need an if / else on my mail function, if mailed, redirect to other page?

Comment: @claudrian, i just dont want to resend mail on refresh, thats all

Comment: Instead of displaying "thank you" after handling $_POST and saving information, save the required information to display in session and redirect your user to a new page using `header("Location: thank_you.php?order_id=xxx");`. If your user refresh, he will only refresh thank_you.php and not the handler. That's as simple as that.

Comment: So after my code, mail() and so on, i add the redirection code "header etc"... that was my question, i thought this wont work, because header redirect needs to be first

Comment: do not display anything in your form handling page, then use `header` anywhere in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by calling the [PHP `header()` function](http://php.net/header) like this:

```
header('Location: thankyou.php');
exit;
```

The user will be redirected to the thankyou page and a reload there will not execute your code again.